# Can I use npm module in a view file in node.js?

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I have this little project that uses a module from npm. But I wanted to use it with angular on a view file that will be used in the server.js(main node.js server file). Is this possible?

[image: project]

this would be the project, use a npm module called "net-snmp" on main.js.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are asking if the module can be used in the browser.

Whether or not a module can be used in the browser depends on the module.  If the module relies on a builtin Node API then you will not be able to use it in the browser unless you shim the module in some way.  The `net-snmp` module you are mentioning will probably not work on a browser.  A quick scan through the source shows it relies on (amongst other things), the `dgram` module for creating sockets.  You can't create sockets from a browser.  There are shim modules like [dgram-browserify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dgram-browserify) that proxy the socket over HTTP but you need server side code to support it.